# Using Powershell to find all User Languages

Tags: powershell, localization

Im trying to find a list of UI languages on Windows 8.1 for some programming. So far I have used:

```
Get-WinUserLanguageList

LanguageTag     : en-AU
Autonym         : English (Australia)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : English (Australia)
ScriptName      : Latin script
InputMethodTips : {0C09:00000409}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
```

This is the exact information that I need however when I try to pipe it to a file, it only does 1 entry.

Is there a way to get this info for all languages?

Comment: The [`Get-WinUserLanguageList`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh852112.aspx) cmdlet returns the current user language settings. In theory you are seeing everything that is configured for that user. If the language is not in use you will not see its data. Are you looking for all languages available? I personnally dont know where that information is.

Comment: Yes, Im looking for all languages. Specifically, LanguageTag, Autonym, EnglishName, LocalizedName, and InputMethodTips.

Answer (score 1):

How about [this](http://powershell.org/wp/2013/04/15/getting-a-list-of-windows-language-locales-with-windows-powershell/)? `[system.globalization.cultureinfo]::GetCultures("AllCultures")`

Comment: Yes I have seen that and use it, however I just need to find the InputMethodTips associated with each field